# Dart, compare two lists and return element from first list that does not exist in second list

Tags: dart

I have two lists,

```
List first = [{'name':'ABC','serialNumber':'ABC-124-353'},
{'name':'XYZ','serialNumber':'XYZ-123-567'},
{'name':'GRE', 'serialNumber': 'GRE-290-128'}];

List second = [{'name':'PQR','serialNumber':'PQR-D123-SII23'},{'name':'GAR','serialNumber':'GAR-G43-432'},
{'name':'MNOP','serialNumber':'XYZ-123-567'}];
```

Is there any easier way to compare `first` list and `second` list by `serialNumber`.
such that element from `first` list that doesn't exist in `second` list are outputted as a result.

So in this case

```
[{'name':'ABC','serialNumber':'ABC-124-353'},{'name':'GRE', 'serialNumber': 'GRE-290-128'}]
```

from `first` list is desired output, because `ABC-124-353` and `GRE-290-128` doesn't exist in list `second`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to use `where` on your `first` List to check if the `serialNumber` is contained in the `second` list:

```dart
final secondSerials = second.map((item) => item['serialNumber']).toSet();
print(first.where((item) => !secondSerials.contains(item['serialNumber'])).toList());
```

Comment: You should also add `.toSet()` on the `secondSerials`, otherwise you lose the efficient lookup, and might as well use `var result = firstList.where((e1) => secondList.every((e2) => e1["serialNumber"] != e2["serialNumber"])).toList();`. (I do recommend using list literals rather than `.where(...).toList()` when possible.)

Comment: Good catch, I added `.toSet()` on the `secondSerials`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a set of the serial numbers of the second list, so that you can do efficient `contains` checks.
So:

```dart
var secondListSerials = {for (var entry in secondList) entry["serialNumber"]};
var firstListOnly = [for (var entry in firstList) 
  if (!secondListSerials.contains(entry["serialNumber"]) entry
];
```